# How to read multiple lines at a time from txt file in C?

Tags: c, io, fastq

I am processing `*.fastq.gz` file, something like the below:

```
@NB501139:187:H2Y5LBGXB:1:11101:17094:1060 2:N:0:CTTTGCGG
AGAGGATCCGTGTGANANNNGANNNCNNCCGNCTNNTANNAGATCACTTAGNNANNNNACAGCAGAAAANNNNNNNNNACAAGGTTGAAANTNTNTNN
+
A/AA///E/////EE#A###//###A##EEE#AE##EA##EE//<AE<EE<##/####/EE</EAE<//#########/E///</EE<<<#E#A#E##
@NB501139:187:H2Y5LBGXB:1:11101:3442:1060 2:N:0:CTTTGCGG
ACTGAGTCACGCACCNANNNCCNNNCNGCCGNCANNGCNNTGCACCGGTGGNCTNNNNTGTGTACTGAGNNTNNNNNNCATGCACACAGANTNCTCNN
+
AAAAAEEEEE/EEE6#<###EE###E#EEE/#AE##<E##EEEEEE/EEEA#EE####EAEEEEEEE/<##A######EEE/E<E/EEE/#A#AEA##
```

The file could be larger than RAM, so I process it block by block using file streaming, then output the result. By block, I mean 4 lines are a block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128

typedef struct fastq
{
    char *id;
    char *seq;
    char *qual;
} fastq;

fastq *get_fastq(gzFile file)
{
    fastq *out = (fastq *)malloc(sizeof(fastq));
    out->id = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    out->seq = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    out->qual = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    char temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    if (gzgets(file, out->id, MAX_LINE_LENGTH) != NULL)
    {
        gzgets(file, out->seq, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        gzgets(file, temp, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        gzgets(file, out->qual, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        free_fastq(out);
        return NULL;
    }

    return out;
}
```

To limit the I/O calling, I am looking for a way to read 4 lines at a time rather than calling `gzgets()` 4 times for one block. I'm unsure if this will save time; any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Unless all lines have a very specific ***fixed*** length then you can't do it. If the lines have a fixed length, then you can read that amount into your own buffer. But be aware, that there are already many possible buffers between you and the actual bytes on the disk, so adding another layer of buffering might not increase the speed as much as you think.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, that's a good suggestion. I probably not going to spend time on this anymore. As the length is not likely fixed.

Comment: You could memory map the whole file and decompress chunks from there. There are examples here on SO

Comment: You are reading _and_ decompressing data from a compressed file. Some decompression algorithms are affected by what has already been read. While reading from the file is one thing, for such algorithms decompression needs to be done serially or you would break the decompression and render the result useless.

Comment: @AviBerger The `gzgets` function handles that

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I understand that. OP wants to read 4 lines at a time rather than making 4 sequential calls to gzgets(). If they get the idea of trying to parallelize things, that will break. Maybe my mental jump was unwarranted, but Some programmer dude
already referenced fixed length lines and these algorithms also change line lengths and don't even respect byte boundaries. The question title also describes this as a text file - it isn't and that is an important distinction that seemed to me to be getting lost.

Comment: @AviBerger _"f they get the idea of trying to parallelize things"_ - Aha, I didn't realize it was that you were thinking about - and yes, unless there are separate compressed streams in the data, parallelizing decompression will be hard :)

Comment: You might want to check out how to use and play around with gzbuffer(). [" gzbuffer . . . Set the internal buffer size used by this library's functions . . . The default buffer size is 8192 bytes.  . . .  A larger buffer size of, for example, 64K or 128K bytes will noticeably increase the speed of decompression "](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h)

Comment: The function `gzgets` will probably use buffering for reading from the compressed file and for the decompression. Slow operations are reading from the file (accessing storage media) and decompression (expensive calculation). Reading from the function's buffer of uncompressed data is probably fast, so that reading one or more lines would not be a big difference. As already written, increasing the internal buffers might help.

Comment: @AviBerger Great discussion here!  I will give `gzbuffer()` a try.  And make an update below. By the way, I am planning a single thread to read and multiple threads to process the reading queue buffer and write the result out.

Comment: @AviBerger `gzbuffer` did show improvement in my application. However, it is difficult to quantify as the application involves other components.